# How can I copy Chrome settings without them getting reset?

Tags: google-chrome

I switched from Firefox to Chrome in Linux because Chrome is faster. Now I'd like to try out Chrome in Windows, and I want to copy my Chrome settings from Linux to Windows.

I found the [location of the user data directory](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory) and simply copied that from Linux to Windows. Chrome then tells me "Chrome detected that some of your settings were corrupted by another program and reset them to their original defaults." I don't think they're actually corrupted. Apparently this is a security feature to [prevent other software from changing Chrome settings](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/4409913?hl=en).

How do I stop Chrome from resetting my settings? Ideally, I don't want my settings reset even if other software changes them, but I would be satisfied with just being able to copy the Chrome settings from Linux. I definitely don't want to log in and sync settings via Google.

Comment: Any luck with this? Did you find a workaround? 
http://superuser.com/questions/951095/understand-structure-of-chrome-user-profile-data-to-transfer-to-new-pc-os-avo?lq=1

@dreamlayers

Comment: I gave up on it and gave up on using Chrome in Windows, because unlike in Linux, it's not significantly faster than Firefox. Conceptually I'm sure it's possible. There's probably just some checksum that needs to match to tell Chrome that the settings haven't been tampered with.